# What should linking Heroku to GitHub repo look like?

Tags: heroku, github

There's a section in the app settings on Heroku called "GitHub Repo" where you can link your app with its GitHub repository. What should the link look like? Is `name/repo` enough or does it have to be a full link, like `https://github.com/name/repo`?

I realize this could be easily tested, but I would like to know without having to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I had the field filled so I didn't see the placeholder. `name/repo` is enough.